# SilverStripe: how to render normal for-each loop in template

Tags: php, loops, silverstripe

Hi I'm new to SilverStripe.

I'm having array of countries `$AllCountries` I want to render in a template using a loop.

If there is model then I can easily do that but I want to do it using an array I have defined over here.

```
Array
    (
        [AD] => Andorra
        [AE] => United Arab Emirates
        [AF] => Afghanistan
        [AG] => Antigua and Barbuda
        [AI] => Anguilla
    );


<select name="Country" class="dropdown form-input" id="country">
        <% loop $AllCountries %>
            <option value="$key">$value</option>
        <% end_loop %>
</select>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ll need to use ArrayList and ArrayData:

```
// MyPage_Controller
public function getOptions() {
    $data = array(
        'AD' => 'Andorra',
        'AE' => 'UAE'
    );

    $result = new ArrayList();
    foreach ($data as $code => $country) {
        $arrayData = new ArrayData(array(
            'Code' => $code,
            'Name' => $country
        ));

        $result->push($arrayData);
    }

    return $result;
}

// MyPage.ss
<select name="Country" class="dropdown form-input" id="country">
    <% loop $Options %>
        <option value="{$Code}">{$Name}</option>
    <% end_loop %>
</select>
```

You might find these helpful:

- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/rendering_templates/
- https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/dealing-with-arbitrary-template-data